# C++/CX: Converting from IVector<T>^ to Vector<T>^

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion, c++-cx

How do I convert from IVector^ to Vector^? Documentation covers the reverse situation which works implicitly, however this one won't compile when I try implicit conversion and compiles but raises exception when I try casting it. I've looked into the reference but I couldn't this covered.

The reason for this is that I wish to store Vector^ inside my class, and use IVector only in a property for communicating with JavaScript as Vector works faster and should be used for internal computation.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
My apologies for being too brief. Here's wider explanation of the situation.

```
if(parent->childNodes != nullptr && parent->childNodes->Size > 0)
    {
        for (uint32 i = 0; i < parent->childNodes->Size; i++)
        {
            ContentElementsNode^ childNode;
            IVector<ContentElementsNode^>^ childNodes = parent->childNodes;
            childNode = childNodes->GetAt(i);

            Vector<ContentElementsNode^>^ childWords = wordObjects(childNode);
            for each (ContentElementsNode^ word in childWords)
                result->Append(word);
        }
    }
```

The function fails at the first call of the GetAt(i) line. I assumed it could be some problem with IVector so I tried to use Vector instead but couldn't cast it. Here's the ContentElementsNode declaration:

```
public ref class ContentElementsNode sealed
{

private:
    IVector<ContentElementsNode^>^ childNodes_;
    String^ textContent_;
    String^ localName_;
    Rectangle boundingBox_;
    String^ id_;
public:
    ContentElementsNode(void);
    property IVector<ContentElementsNode^>^ childNodes {
        void set(IVector<ContentElementsNode^>^ value)
        {
            childNodes_ = value;
        }
        IVector<ContentElementsNode^>^ get()
        {
            return childNodes_;
        }
    }
    property String^ textContent {
        String^ get() {
            return textContent_;
        }
        void set(String^ value) {
            textContent_ = value;
        }
    }
    property String^ localName {
        String^ get() {
            return localName_;
        }
        void set(String^ value) {
            localName_ = value;
        }
    }
    property Rectangle boundingBox {
        Rectangle get() {
            return boundingBox_;
        }
        void set(Rectangle value) {
            boundingBox_ = value;
        }
    }
    property String^ id {
        String^ get() {
            return id_;
        }
        void set(String^ value) {
            id_ = value;
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: The function call should not fail at the line with GetAt().  At what point do you initialize the backing store (childNodes_) with a collection?

Comment: It appears that the front-end part had an error, so invalid value was passed through ABI. As it turns out, the error has no educational purpose whatsoever and the whole thread should then be deleted I assume? Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This would typically be done via `safe_cast<T>`:

```
Vector^ asVector = safe_cast<Vector^>(theIVectorHandle);
```

For details, see the [MSDN article on Casting in C++/CX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755802.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: My bad, it actually doesn't work, I've made a typo while testing.
`Vector<ContentElementsNode^>^ childNodes = safe_cast<Vector<ContentElementsNode^>^>(parent->childNodes);`
Here's how I call it.

Comment: @DamjanDakic Why are you trying to do this cast?  Why not just work with the `IVector<T>^` directly?  That being said - if you want more help, you should show more code, includign the declaration of `childNodes`...

Comment: My apologies, I edited the question I hope it is explanatory enough now.